# Input Field Value Doesn't Clear on Click on iOS

Tags: iphone, vue.js, safari

I have a search form built using Vue that contains one input field. There are two buttons, one to submit and one to cancel (reset) the form.

The cancellation button is not working as expecting. When inspecting in the browser on mobile these works just fine, but NOT on an actual device. Both Safari and Chrome are behaving this way.

For example, the expected behavior when cancelling the form, would be that when clicking the cancel button, the input should clear. The value stays put. I thought perhaps it had something to do with the blur handler since I know this can cause issues, but the blur handler doesn't set the value for the search input.

Relevant code is below.

```
export const QuickSearchBoxSingleBrand = Vue.component("quick-search", {
store,
name: "QuickSearchBoxSingleBrand",
props: {
    id: {
        default: "search",
        type: String
    },
    title: {
        default: "Search",
        type: String
    },
    button: {
        default: "Search",
        type: String
    },
    cancel: {
        default: "Cancel",
        type: String
    },
    icon: {
        default: "/assets/images/svg-sprite.svg#search-icon-sm",
        type: String
    },
},
data: function () {
    return {
        searchTerm: "",
        isOpen: false,
        isActive: false,
    };
},
methods: {      
    handleCancel: function (e) {
        this.isActive = false;
        this.searchTerm = "";
        setFocus(this.$refs.submitBtnEl);
    },
    handleFocus: function (e) {
        this.isActive = true;
    },
    handleBlur: function (e) {
        var isIE11 = !!window.MSInputMethodContext && !!document.documentMode;
        if (!isIE11) {
            const childFocused = e && e.relatedTarget && this.$el.contains(e.relatedTarget);
            if (!childFocused) {
                this.closeSearch()
            }
        }
    }
},
render: function (h) {
    return (
        <form method="post"
            action="/quicksearch/search/"
            class={`search-box search-box--quick ${this.isOpen ? "is-open" : ""} ${this.isActive ? "is-active" : ""}`}
            v-on:submit={this.handleSubmit}
            novalidate>
            {this.$slots.csrf}
            <button type="button"
                aria-expanded={`${this.isOpen ? 'true' : 'false'}`}
                class="search-box__toggle-btn btn btn--link gtm-header-link"
                v-on:click={this.expandSearch}>
                <svg class="icon" role="img" focusable="false">
                    <title>{this.title}</title>
                    {this.$slots.icon}
                </svg>
            </button>
            <div class="search-box__input">
                <label for={this.id} class="u-visuallyhidden">{this.title}</label>
                <input id={this.id}
                    v-model={this.searchTerm}
                    name="searchTerm"
                    class="search-box__field"
                    type="search"
                    v-on:blur={this.handleBlur}
                    v-on:focus={this.handleFocus}
                    ref="searchInputEl" />
                <button type="submit"
                    class="search-box__button gtm-header-link"
                    ref="submitBtnEl"
                    v-on:blur={this.handleBlur}
                    v-on:click={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <svg class="icon" role="img" focusable="false">
                        <title>{this.button}</title>
                        {this.$slots.icon}
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
            <button type="button"
                class="btn btn--link search-box__cancel gtm-header-link"
                v-on:click={this.handleCancel}
                v-on:blur={this.handleBlur}>
                {this.cancel}
            </button>
        </form>
    )
}
```

})